# Findroot and arc length,similar situation but does not work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, equation-solving

In another problem I was presented with this situation
It is to find the arc length of the curve

```
  x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
  y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
```

from t=0 to t =tmax , in such a way that the length is 100 units

which works perfectly

```
FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 1}]
{tmax -> 0.832919}
```

, then an error was discovered in the second equation and I tried to do the same but it does not work.

```
  x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
  y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Cos[t];
  FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 1}]

  (*FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {False} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {tmax} = {1.}.*)
```

I changed it to 2 because at t=2 100 units are produced but it does not work.  I don't understand why

```
FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 2}]
```

Comment: Try: `FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] - 100, {tmax, 1}]`.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk , hi why doesn't it work the other way and why does your way work, can you clarify that for me please?

Comment: `x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Cos[t];
FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] - 100, {tmax, 1}]` give me:`{tmax -> 2.}` and `FindRoot` not give any errors.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk,I think you didn't understand me, yours works and very well, what I ask you is why when you change from a Sin(t) to a Cos(t) it doesn't work for the first form.

Comment: Compare `ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100//Simplify` with `ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] - 100 // Simplify` for both definitions of `y`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon,hi , I understand the comparison, but would you be so kind to tell me why this does not work and I get this error. x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
  y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Cos[t];
  FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 1}]

  (*FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {False} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1}     ,especially this point, {tmax, 1}] what does the 1 there mean? ,if it were 2 , it should work or I am wrong.

Comment: When `FindRoot` plugs a numeric value for `tmax` into the equation, the equation evaluates to the boolean value `False` rather than a scalar (dimension 1).